# Boot Failure for Ubuntu 18.04 Install on Thinkpad P1

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, 18.04, thinkpad, bios

I have a new Lenovo Thinkpad P1 with i7-8850/32GB mem/1TB SSD/P2000 graphics

The laptop came with Windows installed out of the box and I want to dual boot ubuntu along side.

Using Rufus 3.3 I placed a bootable ubuntu 18.04 image on a USB drive. As I understand, Ubuntu 18.04 is UEFI compatible (and supposedly Secure Boot compatible but that seems controversial).

I turn on the computer, F12 to the Boot Menu, select my USB (which takes me to GRUB), select "Install Ubuntu".

Now this is where the problem starts, upon selecting install ubuntu, I am taken to an Ubuntu loading screen (purple background, ubuntu name with dots underneath changing between white and orange) after about 5-15 seconds (very roughly) the computer powers off....

I've tried various combinations of SecureBoot/BootMode/UEFI/etc. settings to no avail in the BIOS.

Help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this post a while back and following it solved my issue with the ubuntu installations. Adding it here for reference. https://medium.com/@rongou/installing-ubuntu-18-04-on-lenovo-thinkpad-p1-9ef814a03390

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it would solve your problem, but the [ArchLinux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Lenovo_ThinkPad_P1#Firmware_update) says you might have boot problems if you're running Hybrid Graphics. You have two options to fix it:

- Disable hybrid graphics by changing your BIOS settings to "Discrete only".
- Alternatively, before booting into live CD, press e and add modprobe.blacklist=nouveau to your kernel parameters.

If you choose to use the second option, you might also want to include `modprobe.blacklist=nouveau` in your `/boot/loader/entries/arch.conf`.

Also: be sure to upgrade the BIOS before trying to install (you can do this in Windows, if you still have it).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll try booting up Manjaro or something and let you know how it goes!

Comment: I'm installing Lubuntu 18.10 on my P1 now and intend to write a blog entry about it. If you ping me with a comment here in a week or to, that'll remind me to post a link in this space.

Comment: did you ever manage to get it working?

Comment: I did! But I forgot to write the post. If I don't reply to this, remind me again soon. @Tshimanga

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the Bios. The default version that shipped with my Lenovo Thinkpad P1 (v1.08) didn't support booting Ubuntu.

Have a look here for the latest one: https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/ca/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-p-series-laptops/thinkpad-p1-type-20md-20me/downloads/ds504958

Comment: Hi Karim, welcome to the site! Are you able to provide a citation or explanation why this might be the case?

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked with "update installer" and then direct into the installer also with the update option so it fetches the latest nvidia driver. Booting into Live didn't work.
I also had to set it to discreet graphics and uefi/legacy (both)
Works like a charm, no hardware issues

Forgot to say I used the latest Kubuntu installer (19 - disco)